# Compiling error in Gcc

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I wrote a program in C.After I compiled it using

```
gcc -o pr prc.c
```

and I got the thing below

```
/usr/bin/ld:cannot find -lc
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: `ld` is the linker, seems it cannot find `-lc`.  Not sure what that is, yet

Comment: You probably did not install a developer package like `libc6-dev` and you should compile with `gcc -Wall -g pr.c -o pr`

Comment: @TonyTheLion: It's trying to link against libc, and cannot find it, for some reason.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch.....hey ..I still get the same thing!!!

Comment: @OliCharlesworth....Thanks for editing my question...
I think that's the cause probably...But I am still not able to figure out how do I get this glibc installed. I tried the sudo apt thing and still its not working!!

Comment: You could run `gcc -v -o pr prc.c` to understand what `gcc` is doing...

Answer (score 3):

The linker (`ld`) can't find library file `libc.{a|so}`, the standard C library. See the [ld man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ld) for mention of this library (and `lc` command line option to `ld`) under section OPTIONS. Quoting:

```
ld -o <output> /lib/crt0.o hello.o -lc

This tells ld to produce a file called output as the result of linking
the file "/lib/crt0.o" with "hello.o" and the library "libc.a"
```

You should check to make sure these files are actually missing from your system. On my Ubuntu 10.04 LTS system:

```
 ~  [88] locate libc.so
/lib/libc.so.6
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
/usr/lib/libc.so

~  [89] locate libc.a
/usr/lib/libc.a
/usr/lib/xen/libc.a
```

How you install this missing library will vary based on your distribution. Use your package manage to search for `libc`. Otherwise, you may want to consider re-installing `gcc`

Comment: downvote(s) *without* explanation help no one. Feel free to point out errors and I'll be happy to improve/correct my answer.

Comment: Well, the actual problem that remains is that I am not able to figure out how do I install this Libc thing. 
I'm using Ubuntu ultimate 2.9

Comment: @Levon...Yes I did that. And it seems like its present in the system already. I got the following thing when I checked,
    ejjy@Rex:~$ locate libc.so

/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so

ejjy@Rex:~$ locate libc.a
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.a
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/xen/libc.a
/usr/share/doc/libklibc/README.klibc.arch

So why do you think, its not being found??

Comment: @ejjy hard to say, at this point it might be easiest to just re-install gcc and be sure to check the development packages too.

Answer (score 3):

-lc is an abbreviation of libc which is the `C` run-time library. What ever your *nix distribution is, you need to install glibc and glibc-common through an appropriate installer.

`man ld` and that should give an insight on the error message. Messages like these indicates that the linker is looking for a missing library. The Name of the library here is libc (replace l with lib).